# Using `wb.save` results in "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to learn how to place an image in an Excel worksheet but I am having a problem with `wb.save`. My program ends with the following error:

```
"C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Don/PycharmProjects/Test 2/Test 2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Don/PycharmProjects/Test 2/Test 2.py", line 20, in <module>
    wb.save('POKENO Cards new.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 75, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 218, in _write_worksheets
    self._write_drawing(ws._drawing)
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 141, in _write_drawing
    self._archive.writestr(drawing.path[1:], tostring(drawing._write()))
  File "C:\Users\Don\PycharmProjects\Test 2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\spreadsheet_drawing.py", line 295, in _write
    self._rels.append(rel)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code. It works until the last statement.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from PIL import Image
#im = Image.open(r"Playing Cards/2C.jpg")
im = Image.open(r"C:/Users/Don/Pictures/resized Nyle.jpg")
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename="C:/Users/Don/PycharmProjects/Test 2/POKENO   Cards.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.worksheets[0]
im.show()
img = im.resize((78, 100))
img.show()
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename="C:/Users/Don/PycharmProjects/Test 2/POKENO Cards new.xlsx")
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.add_image(im, 'A4')
wb2.save(filename="C:/Users/Don/PycharmProjects/Test 2/POKENO Cards new.xlsx")
```

Comment: Your problem is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment". That's literally all we can tell you, though, because you haven't shared any code. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

The error is a bit cryptic, but the Traceback is quite clear enough to trace the cause of the problem: that openpyxl's `add_image` method expects a `openpyxl.drawing.image.Image` object, and not a PIL Image.

If you check the lines in [openpyxl / drawing / spreadsheet_drawing.py](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/drawing/spreadsheet_drawing.html) that raised the error, there's a check there for the image type:

```
for idx, obj in enumerate(self.charts + self.images, 1):
    anchor = _check_anchor(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, ChartBase):
        rel = Relationship(type="chart", Target=obj.path)
        ...
    elif isinstance(obj, Image):
        rel = Relationship(type="image", Target=obj.path)
        ...

    anchors.append(anchor)
    self._rels.append(rel)
```

The problem is that your code

```
im = Image.open(r"C:/Users/Don/Pictures/resized Nyle.jpg")
...
ws2.add_image(im, 'A4')
```

passed in a `'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'` type. It is not a `ChartBase` type or openpyxl's own `Image` type. So `rel` will never be initialized leading to the error that `rel` was used before being assigned something, leading to "*local variable 'rel' referenced before assignment...*".

If you check [openpyxl / drawing / image](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/drawing/image.html#Image), you might notice that openpyxl's `Image` is just a wrapper for PIL's `Image`. It needs a `PIL.Image.Image` object and internally calls `PILImage.open(img)` on the passed image object if it isn't one.

So you might think that converting `img` to openpyxl's `Image` might work.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as XLImage
from PIL import Image as PILImage

im = PILImage.open("my_input_image.png")
pil_img = im.resize((78, 100))
xl_img = XLImage(pil_img)

wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.add_image(xl_img, 'A1')
wb2.save(filename="output.xlsx")
```

That would solve the original error, but then you'll get a new error, "*'Image' object has no attribute 'fp'*", because openpyxl's [Image](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/drawing/image.html#Image) module expects that the image object has a `fp` attribute, which is only available if the Image was created from a file (i.e. `open(filename)`).

So, the solution I can come up with is to:

1. Create the image object as PIL Image
2. Do image pre-processing (ex. resize)
3. Save the pre-processed image back to a file
4. Create the image object as openpyxl's image
5. Add that image to the workbook

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as XLImage
from PIL import Image as PILImage

im = PILImage.open("my_input_image.png")

pil_img = im.resize((78, 100))
pil_img.save("my_resized_image.png")

xl_img = XLImage("my_resized_image.png")

wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.add_image(xl_img, 'A1')
wb2.save(filename="output.xlsx")
```

If you don't need to do any image processing before adding the image, just open the file directly using openpyxl's `Image` class:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as XLImage

xl_img = XLImage("my_input_image.png")

wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.add_image(xl_img, 'A1')
wb2.save(filename="output.xlsx")
```