# Avoid adding an image when it does not exist - python, spreadsheet

Tags: python, file, png, cell, spreadsheet

I wonder how can I omit adding the .png image when it doesn't exist in the folder. Just to leave the space in spreadsheet empty. The simplest way to do it?

```
    logo = Image("./logo.png")
    element = Image("./element.png")
    ws.merge_cells('A1:E3')
    logo.width = 500
    logo.height = 120
    element.width = 140
    element.height = 140
    element.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="left", vertical="center")
    ws.add_image(logo, 'A1')
    ws.add_image(element, 'E1')
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You could somehow "cheat" and insert an image which is all white and has the same dimensions as the valid image.

Comment: @Gameplay Yes, but I wonder what if no pictures are in the folder. Even all white.

Comment: You can create the all white image when the real image is not there:
`img = Image.new("RGB", (logo.height, logo.width), (255, 255, 255))` and insert it.

Comment: @Gameplay thanks, but I can't process this file - _"openpyxl's add_image method expects a openpyxl.drawing.image.Image object, and not a PIL Image"_, more info: [link to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163740/using-wb-save-results-in-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-rel-referenced-b)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

Create the new file using PIL and save it, then open as openpyxl's image to avoid error `AttributeError: fp`

**Code:**

```
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as XLImage
from PIL import Image as PILImage

    ws.merge_cells('A1:E3')
    try:
        logo = XLImage("./Bosch_logo.png")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logo_pil = PILImage.new("RGB", (500, 120), (255, 255, 255))
        logo_pil.save("Bosch_logo_pil.png")
        logo = XLImage("Bosch_logo_pil.png")
    else:   
        logo.width = 500
        logo.height = 120
        
    try:
        element = XLImage("./element.png")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        element_pil = PILImage.new("RGB", (140, 140), (255, 255, 255))
        element_pil.save("element_pil.png")
        element = XLImage("element_pil.png")
    else:  
        element.width = 140
        element.height = 140

    element.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="left", vertical="center")
    ws.add_image(logo, 'A1')
    ws.add_image(element, 'E1')
```

Comment: I think there must be a way to convert Pill to XLImage directly, without saving that unnecessary white image-placeholder.

Comment: @Gameplay It would be great, but openpyxl's Image module expects that the image object has a fp attribute, which is only available if the Image was created from a file